# wordpress site in subdomain on nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I'm having trouble setting up a subdomain with nginx and some wordpress sites.

My www.jackalopegames.com domain is working, but I want to set up dev.jackalopegames.com.

Here's the config file in my sites-enabled folder:

```
server 
{
    listen 80;
    server_name jackalopegames.com www.jackalopegames.com;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_php;

    root /var/sitefolder;

    index index.php;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.jackalopegames.com;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_php;

    root /var/devfolder;

    index index.php;

}
```

The first one `server_name jackalopegames.com` works, but the second one doesn't. I've looked around a bunch and I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working. Any tips would be appreciated!

**Update:**

I've added the following to my subdomain `server {...}` with no effect:

```
location / {
            root   /var/dev;
            index  index.php;
            rewrite ^.*/files/(.*)$ /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^.+/?(/wp-.*) $1 last;
                rewrite ^.+/?(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
                rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
            }
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js)$
        {
            root /var/dev;
            rewrite ^/.*(/wp-.*/.*\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$ $1 last;
            rewrite ^.*/files/(.*(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$/wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
            expires 30d;
            break;
        }

        location ~ wp\-.*\.php|wp\-admin|\.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/dev$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things that you may or may not have already checked.  I had similar issues myself when I first did this.  So, to help with just thing thing, I wrote up a walkthrough for how to do it.  You can find it here:  http://blog.phpadvocate.com/2014/10/setting-up-your-wordpress-blog-as-a-subdomain-with-nginx/